# jQuery animating width of a div with an absolute parent

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate the width of a `div` which is wrapped by a parent element that is positioned `absolute` to it's own parent. It is probably easier to explain by showing an [example of what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/K2UbQ/2/).

What should happen is that when the red rectangle is clicked the width of the green box is animated to a certain width whilst the red rectangle sits alongside it. This all works nice in IE & Firefox, but when running it in chrome the red rectangle jumps below the green box. So I'm just wondering if I've done something stupid or if anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Giving either parent a width big enough to fit the animation seems to fix it, did you try it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong, it's just that the browser thinks there's not enough free space for both elements to be displayed next to each other :)

```
#banner-wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/K2UbQ/8/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the browser thinking that the container div is not large enough to contain both elements.  This is caused by your absolute positioning.  If you must use absolute positioning for this, you will need to ensure that div#banner-wrapper is large enough to accommodate the growth in content.

You can force the width of the div in CSS as x10 says, or change its width using JavaScript in your click handler to open it only as far as you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a border around the `#banner-wrapper` you will see what happens.

It looks like chrome does not re-size the elements once its contents change size (*and thus it causes the floated elements to break since they do not fit in a single line*)..

An alternative would be to use `display:inline-block` for the inner elements.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/K2UbQ/10/